# display property hidden didn't work for paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, display

Why `.d-none .d-sm-block` didn't work in my code?

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
          <h2>heading 1</h2>
          <p class=".d-none .d-sm-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
          <h3>heading 2</h3>
          <p class=".d-none .d-sm-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
          <h3>heading 3</h3>
          <p class=".d-none .d-sm-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
          <h3>heading 4</h3>
          <p class=".d-none .d-sm-block">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to hide those paragraph only on xs. And do as bootstrap official [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) said. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Error-500/pen/WNQxmxN) if you need so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define wrong classname , please remove dots in classname definition. 
example : 
class=".d-none .d-sm-block"

it should be 
class="d-none d-sm-block"

Comment: Thanks @komang Ariana How did I miss it. Really feeling frustrated :)

Comment: sometimes that happen ;)